# How to define module that exports a single function?

Tags: testing, module, ocaml

I've wanted to learn OCaml for many years, and I recently decided to finally go for it, but my first real exposure to OCaml has not been auspicious...

I'm using a set of exercises to learn it (an approach that has worked well for me with other languages).  Each exercise comes with a test script.  The very first test script is this:

```
(* test.ml *)

open Core.Std
open OUnit2
open Mymod

let ae exp got _test_ctxt = assert_equal ~printer:String.to_string exp got

let tests = ["hello" >:: ae "hello!" (echo "hello!");]

let () =
    run_test_tt_main ("tests" >::: tests)
```

I have spent *literally* the entire morning failing to get this to work.

I have tried to find out how to do it in all these places:

https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-4.01/ocaml-4.01-refman.html

https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html

...and several other places, and found *nothing* that looks even close to relevant to the problem (or that works).

Even though there are pages and pages of OCaml documentation out there, I cannot find anything that will tell me how to write the `Mymod` module.

I have tried put any of the following in my `mymod.mli` file:

```
let echo x = x ;;
```

```
let echo : string -> string = fun x -> x ;;
```

```
let echo x : string = x ;;
```

...along with several dozen other variants; they all fail to even compile, let alone pass the tests.  The compiler error messages are impenetrable (e.g.: `illegal begin of interf`), and I can find no documentation to interpret them.

*Neither can I find in the documentation the syntax for defining a function that just returns its (string) input.*

I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on what @camlspotter points out, you should have a `mymod.mli` file like this:

```
val echo : string -> string
```

and a `mymod.ml` file like this:

```
let echo s = s
```

You can compile and run like this:

```
$ ocamlopt -c mymod.mli
$ ocamlopt -c mymod.ml
$ echo 'Printf.printf "saw %s\n" (Mymod.echo "hello world")' > main.ml
$ ocamlopt -o main mymod.cmx main.ml
$ ./main
saw hello world
```

This is described in [Section 2.5 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/moduleexamples.html#sec22).

Answer (score 2):

Write your code in `mymod.ml`, not `mymod.mli`. `*.ml` is for code and `*.mli` is for interface.